# Vueify modal not working properly when using vueify and a master Modal.vue file for modal templates

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I've been trying to follow this http://adamwathan.me/2016/01/04/composing-reusable-modal-dialogs-with-vuejs/ and get it working with Vueify, I managed to do so the other day, then changed to a different method and decided to come back. Now I'm getting an issue where my modals are just rendering on the page itself, not as a modal. I'm using Laravel 5.2 and the latest Vue being pulled in from a CDN in the file my index.blade.php extends.

Modal.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="modal-mask" @click="close" v-show="show" transition="modal">
        <div class="modal-container" @click.stop>
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="babel">

    export default {
        props: ['show', 'onClose'],
        methods: {
            close: function () {
                this.onClose();
            }
        },
        ready: function () {
            document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
                if (this.show && e.keyCode == 27) {
                    this.onClose();
                }
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

NewSaleModal.vue

```
<template>
    <modal :show.sync="show" :on-close="close">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>New Post</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <label class="form-label">
                Title
                <input v-model="title" class="form-control">
            </label>
            <label class="form-label">
                Body
                <textarea v-model="body" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer text-right">
            <button class="modal-default-button" @click="savePost()">
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </modal>
</template>

<script lang="babel">
    export default {
        props: ['show'],
            data: function () {
                return {
                    title: '',
                    body: ''
                }
            },
        methods: {
            close: function () {
                this.show = false;
                this.title = '';
                this.body = '';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

App.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import Modal from './v-components/Modal.vue';
import NewSaleModal from './v-components/NewSaleModal.vue';

Vue.use(VueResource);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {Modal, NewSaleModal},
    data: {
        showModal: false,
    }
});
```

Revelent part from index.blade.php

```
<div class="module" id="app">
        <new-sale-modal :show.sync="showModal"></new-sale-modal>
    <button id="show-modal" @click="showModal = true">New Post</button>
</div>
```

It's ending up just rendering the NewSaleModal to the page like so https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGhw6.png

There's absolutely no errors in my console, when I check the `<NewSaleModal>` in VueDevTools the "show" property is set to false, and in the `<Root>` the showModal variable is also set to false.

Here's my gulpfile and package.json as well.

gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('main.less')
       .browserify('app.js')
       .version([
            './public/css/main.css',
            './public/js/app.js'
       ])
       .browserSync({proxy: 'site.dev'});
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir-vueify": "^1.0.3",
    "notify-send": "^0.1.2",
    "vue-resource": "^0.7.0",
    "vueify": "^8.3.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-1",
    "laravel-elixir-browserify": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Any help on why it's not properly making my NewSaleModal.vue a modal would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a lot of looking I found an answer.

What I was doing wrong was that I was not including the Modal component in my NewSaleModal.vue file. So I added

```
import Modal from './Modal.vue'
```

Before the export default, then added

```
components: {
        Modal
},
```

To the script itself and it fixed my issue.